# return to buffer after exiting terminal, neovim

Tags: neovim, terminal

Most of the time I have my window split, after editing some code, I `:terminal` to run some commands to check if my changes make sense. when I exit the terminal, I don't have the window split anymore, I just lose the buffer that was there before running `:terminal`. When I remember before I close the terminal (cause my fingers are faster than my brain), is that I go in normal mode, and `ctrl-o` to jump back to the previous buffer. does that leave the terminal still running? is there a better way to go close the terminal and go back to my previous split window with buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's what works for me. `Ctrl-o` doesn't close the buffer, it just jumps to the previous one. but `:buffer #` seems to do it. so in my `init.vim` I have

`tnoremap <ESC> <C-\><C-n>:buffer #<CR>`

which closes the terminal buffer and jump back to the previous one, the window is still split. I mapped it to `ESC` cause it makes sense to me, but that's personal preference.